# Using send_file to download a file from Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a download link in my app from which users should be able to download files which are stored on s3. These files will be publicly accessible on urls which look something like

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/:bucket_name/:path/:to/:file.png
```

The download link hits an action in my controller:

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
    send_file(@attachment.file.url, disposition: 'attachment')
  end
end
```

But I get the following error when I try to download a file:

```
ActionController::MissingFile in AttachmentsController#show

Cannot read file https://s3.amazonaws.com/:bucket_name/:path/:to/:file.png
Rails.root: /Users/user/dev/rails/print

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:9:in `show'
```

The file definitely exists and is publicly accessible at the url in the error message.

How do I allow users to download S3 files?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to send a file from your web server,

- you need to download it from S3 (see [@nzajt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028162/980524)) or
- you can `redirect_to @attachment.file.expiring_url(10)`

Comment: how can I use this with non-public files on S3?

Comment: @MehulKar in that case you need to use ``@attachment.file.expiring_url``

Comment: Note when accessing private files on S3 as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138994/awss3s3object-url-for-how-to-do-this-with-the-new-aws-sdk-gem), the S3 URL will contain your secret AWS credentials so the browser can make an authenticated request. It won't be obvious if the download works and the user flow stays on your page, but when it doesn't work (for example the file doesn't exist) then the error page on S3 will have the credentials visible on the URL. This is a pretty big security risk.

Comment: redirecting to the url doesn't automatically download the file, it just brings you to a browser view of it where you can *then* download it

Comment: I know this post is old, but because this comment is referenced multiple times: *no*, expiring urls do **not** leak your credentials. they show your access *id* which is not a secret, and a presigned **hash** for authentication. if presigned urls gave out your credentials, people could just recreate urls over and over again when the url expired

Answer (score 92):

You can also use [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data).

I like this option because you have better control. You are not sending users to s3, which might be confusing to some users.

I would just add a download method to the `AttachmentsController`

```
def download
  data = open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/PATTH TO YOUR FILE") 
  send_data data.read, filename: "NAME YOU WANT.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: 'inline', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096' 
end
```

and add the route

```
get "attachments/download"
```

Comment: So in this solution the `open` method does not download the entire file first?  And send_data can stream the file from amazon to the user without the user ever knowing the real s3 file path?

Comment: Definitely this way, however it seems that the `stream` & `buffer_size` options are not needed https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/data_streaming.rb  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data so just `send_data data.read, type: image.content_type, disposition: 'inline'` to render in browser

Comment: For large files, this can be confusing for the user who waits for the server to download the file first and then stream it to the user. Plus, it takes up to twice as long then just having the user download directly from S3.

Comment: WIth a carrierwave+S3 file, I made it work like this :
    ```article = Article.find params[:id]``` ```file_data = open(article.file.url)``` ```send_data file_data.read, filename: article.filename, type: article.file.content_type, disposition: 'attachment'```

Comment: Worth pointing out in addition to @JoshPinter's observation of it being slower (because the data goes through an intermediary instead of direct), it also puts extra load on your server and is blocking, though you can offload it to a background task. Downloading the file directly from S3 is more efficient plus S3 has decent error pages - but [your AWS credentials will be visible when accessing private files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277971/using-send-file-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3#comment63642384_12278021).

Comment: This is really not a good idea. You store all the file data in memory before you pass it on. Depending on the file size, this can get you ending up with a "No space left on device" exception.

Comment: For us redirecting to S3 isn't a good option, the files we send are not public, so we only want certain users to download said files. I have been doing this for years and never run into a disk space issue, but it could happen if you are using a small server. I also like controlling the user experience, so the download doesn't come from some random S3 or cloudfront url.

Comment: @HoloHokkaido Your comment is what finally worked for me.

Answer (score 38):

### Keep Things Simple For The User

I think the best way to handle this is using an expiring S3 url. The other methods have the following issues:

- The file downloads to the server first and then to the user.
- Using `send_data` doesn't produce the expected "browser download".
- Ties up the Ruby process.
- Requires an additional `download` controller action.

My implementation looks like this:

#### In your `attachment.rb`

```
def download_url
  S3 = AWS::S3.new.buckets[ 'bucket_name' ] # This can be done elsewhere as well,
                                            # e.g config/environments/development.rb
  url_options = { 
    expires_in:                   60.minutes, 
    use_ssl:                      true, 
    response_content_disposition: "attachment; filename=\"#{attachment_file_name}\""
  }

  S3.objects[ self.path ].url_for( :read, url_options ).to_s
end
```

#### In your views

```
<%= link_to 'Download Avicii by Avicii', attachment.download_url %>
```

That's it.

---

If you still wanted to keep your `download` action for some reason then just use this:

**In your `attachments_controller.rb`**

```
def download
  redirect_to @attachment.download_url
end
```

*Thanks to [guilleva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426114/293280) for his guidance.*

Comment: Does this download the whole bucket? I have a similar method where I am downloading individual bucket objects based on their key.

Comment: @BigRon No, just the individual object _in_ the bucket. But looking at my code snippets again, I think I've sliced out an important part! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @BigRon Take a look at that now. Added the piece where you use the S3 bucket to actually get the object.

Comment: nice correction, that looks right. I'll have to try your use of `self.path`. It looks like a more simple usage than my current method

Comment: @BigRon Let me know if `self.path` works for you or not because we actually have a check that strips out the leading slash but I wasn't sure if that was necessary in all cases or if we have something special in our case: `self.path.chr == '/' ? self.path[1..-1] : self.path )`

Comment: BTW, I edited this to use double quotes around the header filename. We ran into an issue where some versions of Internet Explorer (of course) was including the single quotes as part of the downloaded filename. Using double quotes seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: How can I download the file inline? My browser opens files in a new tab. I'm using Heroku + Passenger, maybe I have to add an .htaccess file to specify inline downloads?

Comment: Hi Joshua, I am using paperclip with files as private. it works all good. Thoguh on certain occasions i would like the user be able to download the file instead of opening it in the browser tab. Is there a way to add `response_content_disposition` in the controller instead of the model ?

Comment: @Maxence What if you just add a param for the models' `download_url` method that allows you to change how it's dealt with?

Answer (score 6):

I have just migrated my `public/system` folder to Amazon S3. Solutions above help but my app accepts different kinds of documents. So if you need the same behavior, this helps for me:

```
@document = DriveDocument.where(id: params[:id])
if @document.present?
  @document.track_downloads(current_user) if current_user
  data = open(@document.attachment.expiring_url)
  send_data data.read, filename: @document.attachment_file_name, type: @document.attachment_content_type, disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

The file is being saved in the `attachment` field of `DriveDocument` object.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

The following is what ended up working well for me. Getting the raw data from the S3 object and then using `send_data` to pass that on to the browser.

Using the `aws-sdk` gem documentation found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html

**full controller method**

```
def download
  AWS.config({
    access_key_id: "SECRET_KEY",
    secret_access_key: "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  })

  send_data( 
    AWS::S3.new.buckets["S3_BUCKET"].objects["FILENAME"].read, {
      filename: "NAME_YOUR_FILE.pdf", 
      type: "application/pdf", 
      disposition: 'attachment', 
      stream: 'true', 
      buffer_size: '4096'
    }
  )
end
```

Comment: This has to download the file to the server before sending to the user, correct?

Comment: Correct, may not be an option depending on how large your files are. In my case they are small PDFs and this was acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I allow users to download S3 files?

If you're able to **set some metadata on the file BEFORE you upload it to S3** instead of trying to patch it when the user wants to download it later, then this solution is much simpler:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24297799/763231

> If you are using `fog` then you can do something like this:
>
> ```
> has_attached_file :report,
>   fog_file: lambda { |attachment|
>     {
>       content_type: 'text/csv',
>       content_disposition: "attachment; filename=#{attachment.original_filename}",
>     }
>   }
> ```
>
> If you are using Amazon S3 as your storage provider, then something
> like this should work:
>
> ```
> has_attached_file :report
>   s3_headers: lambda { |attachment|
>     { 
>       'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
>       'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=#{attachment.original_filename}",
>     }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

def download_pdf
    @post=  @post.avatar.service_url

```
send_data(

    "#{Rails.root}/public/#{@post}",
    filename: "#{@post}",
    type: "image/*",
    disposition: 'inline', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096'
)
```

end

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.