# MissingFile error in rails after send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I implemented a simple pixel tracker for emails. When calling my controller method I use `send_file` to respond with a gif image in an html email template.

```
send_file 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxx.gif', :type => 'image/gif', :disposition => 'inline'
```

Now everytime the image is loaded I get

> An ActionController::MissingFile occurred in emails#mail_check:
>
> Cannot read file
>   https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eventbaxx/xxxxxxxxxxx.gif
>   app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:90:in `mail_check'

I realize that it might have to do with access rights but I set the file to public and I can also access the image via my browser so that should not be the problem.

My app is hosted on heroku.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do send_file with a file which isn't on your server.  You can copy the file to your server, and send it, or you can redirect to the file which is the more efficient option.

See [Using send_file to download a file from Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277971/using-send-file-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3)