# send_file error: ActionController::MissingFile - Cannot read file - from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

Generated a presigned_url for a csv file on S3. If I put the url in the browser it opens without any issues.

I want the user to be able to click a link and have the file download onto their computer without touching the server if possible.

The following fails with the error:

```
ActionController::MissingFile at /foo/1/download
Cannot read file FILE_URL

class FooController < ApplicationController

  def download
    @foo = Foo.find_by( id: params[:id] )
    send_file( @foo.url, filename: @foo.filename )
  end

end
```

This redirect works without a problem and the file is displays in the browser.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def download
    @foo = Foo.find_by( id: params[:id] )
    redirect_to @foo.url
  end

end
```

Comment: For anyone that finds this, you can't use send_file with files that aren't local

Comment: Why not use redirect if that is working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To download files from s3 you need to use [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) over `send_files`.

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028162/4296747) for a full example