# How to get file stream in the output of Object.get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I a writing a Rails API, with help of [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby), which retrieves a file from AWS and returns in the response of API. Can I get somehow file stream in response of [object.get](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html), which I can directly return from the Rails API.

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket_name = "my_bucket"
bucket = s3.bucket(bucket_name)
object = bucket.object("a/b/my.pdf")
Rails.logger.info 'Downloading file to AWS'
downloaded_data = object.get({})
send_data(downloaded_data,
    :filename => "my.pdf",
    :type => "mime/type"
)
```

But it does not return file.

One option I know is to first save the file in local using this line:

```
object.get(response_target: '/tmp/my.pdf')
```

Than I can return this file *but is there a way to skip this step and directly return the response of `object.get` without saving in local*.

I can not use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278021/1610034) solution as my URL are not public and I am just creating a REST API.

I got screen like following when I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028162/1610034) solution.

[image]

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, that question is different, as there files are already publicly accessible via URLs.

Comment: Did it not work for you? If not, I'll reopen the question.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko In my case, one thing, I have just REST APIs returning file, not full Rails application, second no public URL for content.

Answer (score 0):

As of now what I am doing is getting a URL from the object like this:

```
url = object.presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 3600)
```

and using following code to send the response:

```
data = open(url)
send_data data.read, filename: file_name, type: "mime/type"
```