# What can be possible values of response-content-type in object.get API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

What can be possible values of response-content-type in [object.get](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html#RESTObjectGET-responses-examples) API.

It's description says:

> Sets the Content-Type header of the response.
>
> Type: String

But I don't see possible values in the docs.

Why I ask is one of the possible value might help in solving this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43468397/1610034).

Answer (score 0):

There is no list of the possible values, because `Content-Type` is provided by you, [when you upload the object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html).  The value can be any syntactically valid MIME type, expressed as [`type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter)`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7).

If you provide nothing with the upload, the value is set to the default generic MIME type `binary/octet-stream` which specifies that the object is to be understood by the user agent as a stream of octets (bytes) with no declared meaning.