# How protect the paperclip attachment files for download in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html5-video

I'm creating an application with rails to upload videos, for that I use the paperclip gem

My problem is that any user can download the video with the paperclip url, and i dont want that

Is there any way do:

- Can prevent the download of attachments files with paperclip?
- Or some configuration so that when the paperclip file url is accessed redirects to another view?
- Or some way to hide the url in the video tag in html5?
- Or some way to protect the download of public folder of Ruby on Rails project?
- Or something can prevent download files in Ruby on Rails?

That is the model i use

```
class VideoEpisode < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :video, :url  => "/assets/episode_video/:id/:basename.:extension",
              :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/episode_video/:id/:basename.:extension"


validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/  


end
```

I'm using

- rails 4.2.5.1
- ruby 2.1.8p440

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using send\_file to download a file from Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277971/using-send-file-to-download-a-file-from-amazon-s3)

Comment: you probably want something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028162/525478, with authentication on the method in question.

Comment: I cant use Amazon S3, and the problem is went the user get the url of src of video tag, he can access to the video to download with the HTML5 VideoPlayer and i dont know how avoid that

Comment: The same way, you just upload to a local private folder and require authentication for the destination.

Comment: Ok, i gona try, thanks