# How to present credentials to s3 using open-uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, open-uri

I need to download assets from Amazon s3.I am not currently able to test my code, because I don't have the credentials. I think the following should work:

```
open(url, http_basic_authentication: [username, password])
```

...assuming that `url`, `username`, and `password` are what they say they are. I just don't know if this will work with s3 specifically. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138994/awss3s3object-url-for-how-to-do-this-with-the-new-aws-sdk-gem) It shows how to generate a secure URL for your resource.

Comment: I was specifically wondering whether I could do it through openURI, given the access key and secret key.